# How do I log in on another device? Also "my logins" is broken.

Tags: support, user-accounts, login

I tried to login on another device and the login page asks for my email instead of my username like it used to. I tried putting my username in instead but it said it was invalid. Leaving it blank gave the same message. I then tried setting my email in my profile to user61295@stackexchange.com(it was blank before) and logging in with that but it says no account with that email found. I tried clicking my logins to see if that told me what to put but it just shifts some of the text to the left for a second and then shifts it back, unless I click it again and then it says I may only load it every three seconds but still doesn't give any infomation.( I am using the default Android browser and I have javascript enabled). I tried clicking  the recover my your account link but that wants an email too.

Comment: When you say the "my logins" link is broken, what do you mean?  It should pop up a box with your credentials - in your case, your 3rd party OpenID provider.

Comment: I don't see a box.I just see the "edit prefs flair apps my logins line shift to the left for a second or 2, without a box appearing(unless I click it twice in a row, then I see the box that says I should wait 3 seconds, but still no box with my logins.). Also, I don't remember signing up for anything third-party.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the "my logins" box by scrolling randomly. It was two screens below and one screen to the right of the "my logins" link. I discovered that I have a MyOpenID I hadn't used since febuary. I managed to log in with it and am now looking for another OpenID provider since apparently MyOpenID might be going down.